# Fanxybox ajax popup - full HTML or just content?

Tags: ajax, popup, fancybox

I've created a website which uses Fancybox to for ajax popups (mainly forms). The content for these popups is loaded from a PHP file. Everything works well.

My actual question is: should the Fancybox popup page contain

A) full HTML (with doctype, head, css-includes etc), or

B) just the HTML for the form, similar to inline version of Fancybox. Fancybox documentation uses this in their examples.

I've tested with both and they both work, with minor differences:

- datepicker only works when it is initialized within the popup
- css files are usable in the popup in both
- difficult to test for HTML validity in version B
- version A works even should Fancybox break down for any reason

This is why I tend to go for option a, but am I missing something here? Are the issues I'm not considering? I do not want to use an inline version as there are many forms on a page, and very few of which are used at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are subtle differences your should consider :

1). When you load content via **ajax**, the content becomes part of your current document and the ajaxed elements will be affected by the CSS and JS settings of the (parent) page where the content was loaded.

In other words, any (CSS and JS) functionality you want from that ajaxed content (ideally) needs to be previously initialized in the parent page (using a *delegated* form) or initializing them inside the fancybox callbacks (`afterShow` for fancybox v2.x)

In that case, the returned content (from the php file) doesn't need a full structure (`DOCTYPE`, `<head>`, `<link>` or `<script>` tags) but the HTML elements of the content body.

**Bottom line** : parent page and ajax content become one single document (although ajaxed elements will be removed from the DOM after closing fancybox)

**NOTE** : elements in the ajaxed page can affect or conflict with elements in the parent page.

2). On the other hand, you could have an independent and a fully functional page (`DOCTYPE`, `<head>`, `<link>` or `<script>` tags, etc.) with its own CSS and JS functionality.

This page can be loaded into fancybox via **iframe** mode and its DOM elements won't be affected by the CSS and JS settings of the parent page (elements in the the parent page won't be affected by elements in the iframed page either)

**Bottom line** : parent page and iframe content are two separated documents regardless the view.

> what do you need to use?

You may want to use `iframe` if you prefer not to load and initialize many scripts in the parent page, but this is a question with many answers and it's up to you to decide what's best.